# Question on Convergence in distribution

Tags: distributions, convergence

[Belyaev and Sjöstedt-de Luna](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3215615?seq=1) introduced the notion of **weakly approaching sequences of distributions**, generalizing the weak convergence without imposing the limiting distribution.

> *Definition*. Two sequences of random variables $\{Y_n\}$ and $\{X_n\}$ are said to have *weakly approaching distributon laws*, $\{\mathcal{L}(Y_n)\}$ and $\{\mathcal{L}(X_n)\}$, if for any bounded continuous function $f$, $E(f(Y_n))-E(f(X_n))\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, and we write $\mathcal{L}(Y_n) \overset{w.a.}{\longleftrightarrow}\mathcal{L}(X_n), \ n\to\infty$.

I know that $Y_n$ converges in distribution/weakly to $X$, denoted by $Y_n\overset{d}{\to}X$, if for any bounded continuous function $f$, $E(f(Y_n))-E(f(X))\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, by portmanteau Lemma.

**My question is**: when $\mathcal{L}(Y_n) \overset{w.a.}{\longleftrightarrow}\mathcal{L}(X_n)$ will imply $Y_n\overset{d}{\to}X$?

I believe that $X_n\overset{d}{\to}X$ is sufficient. But I cannot argue why.

**My attempt**

Suppose that $X_n\to X$ in distribution. Then the portmanteau Lemma (see Lemma 2.2 of [Van der Vaart's Asymptotic Statistics](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/asymptotic-statistics/A3C7DAD3F7E66A1FA60E9C8FE132EE1D)) gives $\mathcal{L}(X_n) \overset{w.a.}{\longleftrightarrow}\mathcal{L}(X)$. Therefore
$$E(f(Y_n))-E(f(X))=E(f(Y_n))-E(f(X_n))+E(f(X_n))-E(f(X))\to 0$$
for any bounded continuous $f$, by hypothesis.

This shows that if $\mathcal{L}(Y_n) \overset{w.a.}{\longleftrightarrow}\mathcal{L}(X_n)$  and $X_n\overset{d}{\to}X$, then $\mathcal{L}(Y_n) \overset{w.a.}{\longleftrightarrow}\mathcal{L}(X)$ .
By portmanteau Lemma again, $\mathcal{L}(Y_n) \overset{w.a.}{\longleftrightarrow}\mathcal{L}(X)$ implies $Y_n\overset{d}{\to}X$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just an comment on nomenclature: it's the 'portmanteau lemma', from the word 'portmanteau', indicating that it has a lot of things stuffed in together.  It's not named after a Monsieur Portmanteau

Comment: @ThomasLumley thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is a simple case of combining two limits into one.  In the present case the condition is *necessary and sufficient*, so you have a stronger result than the one you are positing.

> **Theorem:** Suppose that $\mathcal{L}(Y_n) \overset{w.a.}{\longleftrightarrow}\mathcal{L}(X_n)$.  Then for any random variable $L$ we have:
>   $$X_n\overset{d}{\to}L \quad \iff \quad Y_n\overset{d}{\to}L.$$
>
> **Proof:** Let $f$ be an arbitrary bounded continuous function, so we have the limit: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(f(Y_n)) - \mathbb{E}(f(X_n)) = 0.$$
>   ($\implies$) 
>   Since $X_n\overset{d}{\to}L$ we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(f(X_n)) - \mathbb{E}(f(L)) = 0$ which gives: $$\begin{aligned}
> \text{Limit}
> &\equiv \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(f(Y_n)) - \mathbb{E}(f(L)) \\[6pt]
> &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \Big[ \mathbb{E}(f(Y_n)) - \mathbb{E}(f(X_n)) + \mathbb{E}(f(X_n)) - \mathbb{E}(f(L)) \Big] \\[6pt]
> &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \Big[ \mathbb{E}(f(Y_n)) - \mathbb{E}(f(X_n)) \Big] 
> + \lim_{n \to \infty} \Big[ \mathbb{E}(f(X_n)) - \mathbb{E}(f(L)) \Big] \\[6pt]
> &= 0+0 = 0. \\[6pt]
> \end{aligned}$$
>   The proof of the reverse implication ($\impliedby$) is identical.  $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, if $E(f(Y_n))-E(f(X_n))\to 0$ and $E(f(X_n))-E(f(X))\to 0$, elementary facts about sequences would tell you 
$$
E(f(Y_n))-E(f(X))\to 0,
$$
i.e. (since $f$ is arbitrary bounded and continuous function)
$$
Y_n\overset{d}{\to}X.
$$

(Necessity also holds as well as sufficiency. Suppose $\mathcal{L}(Y_n) \overset{w.a.}{\longleftrightarrow}\mathcal{L}(X_n)$, then $Y_n$ converges in distribution if and only  $X_n$ does also.)